# Character Encoding & Databases

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having a big problem with character encoding accross my domains.  The big thing for me really is that I don't understand it.  I set all my websites to be utf-8 using the meta tag:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Which seemed to have solved a few problems a while back.  Now I am seeing problems with between the website and the database, when a user enters their first or last name, and it has an accent in it, it doesnt display correctly.  However I ran the following test.

I created a test table called 'test' (imaginative I know)

I wrote a very tiny script to take the value from a text box and put it into this table and then display the contents of this table each time this page displays, so I could see what is going on.

Here are some screen shots, first, from the output of the page:

[image: The <code>var_dump</code> of the database results I get from tabe 'test']

And then a screenshot of the database itself:
[image: Quick view of phpMyAdmin table <code>test</code>]

So the type of column `first` is `VARCHAR(50)`, I just left the settings as I would do normally, and the character encoding was latin_swedish1 or something.  After `id` 4, I changed it `utf8_bin`, but that still didnt make a difference.

The problem is, the data still display okay on the website, but looks terrible in the database.  Is that a problem, is this how it should be done? I think the problems I the users are complaining about are when it is put into emails and PDFs etc, which I don't think I set character encoding on.

Any help and advice would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have the charset is utf8 when you created the table. 
create table my_table (
id int primary key,
.....
) engine=innodb charset=utf8;

and make sure that your connection is setting the charset for utf8. it depends on each framework you're using.

You can set internal character to utf-8 /* Set internal character encoding to UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: Thank you, I set the charset when connecting and the actual database and rows to utf8_general_ci.  They never tell you this when running you through database connection tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

When the3 column type was assigned, how was it assigned?  I would ensure that it was along the lines of `VARCHAR(n) CHARSET utf8` as that would make your column type correct for the UTF8 standard, more normally I see the UCS2 (`VARCHAR(n) CHARSET ucs2`) which can then cause problems later down the line.

you can set this using `NVARCHAR` ( see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-national.html) since sql 5.

To change the type of a column on its own you can use this type of command:

`Alter table tablenamehere MODIFY columnidhere newdatatypehere;`

for example

`Alter table mytabelforphp MODIFY oldvarcharcolumnId nvarchar(1024);`

Let me know if you need more info:)

Comment: I am just using the phpMyAdmin interface to assign the column.  As I mentioned, i changed it before id:5 however it still seemed to produce strange characters in the database.  Is utf8_bin the right one to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `utf8_general_ci`. This will  solve troubles.

Comment: It still looks strange in the database (as seen above) - is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

also add your character encoding to database connection 
if you have mysqli connection use : 
[mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

if you use PDO follow this:

[PDO_MYSQL DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)